Is there a reason not to use secondary server(s)?
Views have settings and one of the settings is:
Use Secondary Server: This will make the query attempt to connect to a replica server if available. If no replica server is defined or available, it will fall back to the default server.
This is located on admin/structure/views/view/{view_name}
Then, Advanced > Other > Query settings
I have database replication setup and configured in Drupal. I am considering updating all the views to use a secondary server.
My question is why would I not want views using secondary servers?  Will selecting this cause some views not to work correctly?

I've never used that option. I didn't even know it exists. I think if the first server fails my website would be down anyways, so no need for a secondary server, if my website can't load the page with that view in the first place.

You would use a replica server for views for the same reason you would use it for a site. I do not see that setting on a plain Drupal installation, but I hope it is a checkbox to enable it and use the replica server(s) set in the settings.php file.

The "Secondary Server" feature was originally introduced in the Views module in 2010: https://www.drupal.org/node/985602. That said, core itself uses replicas widely by default and only temporarily disables using them during entity database operations.

Cost and ability. It costs more and takes more knowledge to be able to set up multiple servers.

I switch all my views to use the secondary servers. No issues so far.
